# Interaction between Termcal package and \date{}

Tags: tufte, termcal

I'm preparing course documents for the fall, using the `tufte-handout` class, and I want to incorporate a calendar using `termcal`. So I do this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{termcal}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\calprintclass}{}

\title{Course overview}
\author{English 220}
\date{Fall 2017}

    \begin{document}

        \maketitle

        \begin{fullwidth}

            \setlength{\calwidth}{6in}
            \begin{calendar}{9/4/17}{10}

                \calday[Monday]{\classday} % Monday
                \calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
                \calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
                \calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday (unnumbered)
                \calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday
                \skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
                % Holidays
                \options{9/21/17}{\noclassday}
                \caltext{9/21/17}{No Class\\Rosh Hashanah}

                % Key dates

                \caltext{9/5/17}{Introductions}

                \caltext{9/18/17}{Bring to class \emph{TOTC} \& \emph{The Passion}}

                % Exams
                \caltext{9/15/17}{Review test on 9th grade grammar \& vocab}
                \caltext{9/29/17}{Quiz on vocab list 7}
                \caltext{10/20/17}{Quiz on vocab lists 7--8}
                \caltext{10/27/17}{Quiz on adj. \& adv. clauses}



            \end{calendar}
        \end{fullwidth}
    \end{document}
```

The output is bizarre. I would post an image, but for some reason I can't make that happen at the moment (follow that drama [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/can-no-longer-post-an-image-with-my-questions) if you're curious), so I'll have to describe it.

- The first date in the calendar is correct (Sep. 4); the subsequent dates are Oct. -25, Nov. -55, Dec. -84, Jan. -114, and so forth. (Yes, the dates are negative numbers.)
- The cell for Sep. 4 also contains the expression "Fall 2017>30". The second cell (Oct. -25) contains "Fall 2017>31", and so forth.

So it looks like `termcal` has a problem with the line

```
\date{Fall 2017}
```

## Miscellaneous observations:

- If I change that line to `\date{}`, I get a bunch of error messages, and no date line in my title block, but the calendar displays correctly.
- If I delete the date line entirely, the title block contains today's date (which I do not want), but the calendar displays correctly.
- If I change the document class to `article`, the problem goes away entirely.

Is there a way to use the `date` command the way I typically do and still have `termcal` work properly? Or is this package just incompatible with this document class?

Comment: Apparently, `\date{Fall 2017}` is nothing what `termcal` understands. But at the moment I can't compile your document at all

Comment: Right, but why does it need the `\date` command at all? The starting date of the calendar is one of the arguments to \begin{calendar}; isn't that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blame `termcal` or `tufte-common.def` -- both define and use`\thedate` ;-)

`tufte-common.def` sets `\thedate` by using the argument of `\date` which is a bad idea, because `\the...` macros should be usually used only for counter output.

`termcal` defines a new counter named `date`, which implies the automatic definition of `\thedate`, however, this is done with `\gdef\thedate{...}`, overwritting the old definition by `tufte-common.def`.

Actually, `tufte-common.def` is doing here something ill-designed.

A solution, rather than changing the apparently proper behaviour of `termcal` is to grab the original `\date` command designed by `LaTeX` before the `\documentclass` comes into action, say with `\let\latexdate\date` and saying `\latexdate{Fall 2017}` instead of `\date{Fall 2017}`, which screws the system up.

```
\let\latexdate\date

\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{termcal}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\calprintclass}{}

\title{Course overview}
\author{English 220}
\latexdate{Fall 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{fullwidth}

  \setlength{\calwidth}{6in}
  \begin{calendar}{9/4/17}{10}

    \calday[Monday]{\classday} % Monday
    \calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
    \calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
    \calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday (unnumbered)
    \calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday
    \skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
    % Holidays
    \options{9/21/17}{\noclassday}
    \caltext{9/21/17}{No Class\\Rosh Hashanah}

    % Key dates

    \caltext{9/5/17}{Introductions}

    \caltext{9/18/17}{Bring to class \emph{TOTC} \& \emph{The Passion}}

    % Exams
    \caltext{9/15/17}{Review test on 9th grade grammar \& vocab}
    \caltext{9/29/17}{Quiz on vocab list 7}
    \caltext{10/20/17}{Quiz on vocab lists 7--8}
    \caltext{10/27/17}{Quiz on adj. \& adv. clauses}



  \end{calendar}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

**Better version with redefinition of `\date` depending whether termcal is loaded or not**

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{termcal}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\tuftedate{}
\@ifpackageloaded{termcal}{%
  \renewcommand{\date}[1]{%
    \gdef\@date{#1}%
    \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
    \protected@xdef\tuftedate{#1}%
    \endgroup%
  }{%
    % Do nothing else, there's no need to redefine \date
  }
}
\makeatother
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\calprintclass}{}

\title{Course overview}
\author{English 220}
\date{Fall 2017}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{fullwidth}

  \setlength{\calwidth}{6in}
  \begin{calendar}{9/4/17}{10}

    \calday[Monday]{\classday} % Monday
    \calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
    \calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
    \calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday (unnumbered)
    \calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday
    \skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
    % Holidays
    \options{9/21/17}{\noclassday}
    \caltext{9/21/17}{No Class\\Rosh Hashanah}

    % Key dates

    \caltext{9/5/17}{Introductions}

    \caltext{9/18/17}{Bring to class \emph{TOTC} \& \emph{The Passion}}

    % Exams
    \caltext{9/15/17}{Review test on 9th grade grammar \& vocab}
    \caltext{9/29/17}{Quiz on vocab list 7}
    \caltext{10/20/17}{Quiz on vocab lists 7--8}
    \caltext{10/27/17}{Quiz on adj. \& adv. clauses}



  \end{calendar}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Why does `\let\latexdate\date` go before the class declaration?

Comment: @crmdgn: Because `tufte-handout` redefines `\date`, you have to save it before. I am thinking of a better solution however

Comment: @crmdgn: Updated with a cleaner version

Comment: Fascinating. How does the `\thanks` command come into it?

Comment: @crmdgn: The `\thanks` commands is from the `tufte` version of `\date`. I've kept it.